# Use perl array in javascript

Tags: javascript, perl

I am developing perl application, I would like to print perl array in my javascript alert, but it just does not work, and here is my code

```
sub leaveInfo{
            my ( $title_id ) = @_;
            $sql = "SELECT tab_timeslot.`location` , tab_timeslot.`date` , tab_timeslot.`time` , tab_timeslot.`end_time`
            FROM tab_appointment
            INNER JOIN tab_timeslot ON tab_appointment.timeslot_id = tab_timeslot.timeslot_id
            WHERE tab_appointment.lecture_id ='" . $title_id ." '";
            $query = &statement_database($sql);
            my @co; 
            my @arro;
            my $num = 0;
            while(my(@co)=$query->fetchrow_array){
             push (@arro,$co[$num]);
            $num++; 
            }
            print @arro;

        }   

        print '<script type="text/javascript">' . "\n" .
              '   Check = confirm("Do you really want to leave this lecture?'.leaveInfo(1215).'");' . "\n" .
              '   if (Check == false) history.back();' . "\n" .
              '   else                location.href="index.pl?value=my_events&to_do=leave_lecture_exec&user_id=' . $cgi->param('user_id') . '&title_id=' . $cgi->param('title_id') . '"' .  "\n" .
              '</script>' . "\n";



        }
```

the alert only shows the number of how much object that stored in the array not the value of the array itself, any help will be helpfull

Comment: There's far too much noise in this example, please make a [**short** self contained example](http://sscce.org/). Is the complicated way you construct the array important? If you printed the same output on the command line what do you see?

Comment: it will print the value of the array, but when i put it in alert, it will only show the number

Comment: Don't show us Perl and tell us JavaScript doesn't work. Either show us JavaScript and ask any it doesn't work, or show us Perl, the JavaScript you want it to generate and the JavaScript that it does generate and ask why it it doesn't generate what you want.

Comment: You've got an XSS security hole there (and I wouldn't be surprised if you has an SQL injection hole too). **escape** data when moving it between contexts.

Comment: i just want to describe that i cant pass the value from perl array to javascript, can you get the clear explanation if I ask you something like "i cant move my perl array to javascript alert, how to do it?"

Answer (score 1):

To get the output you said you got, you have

```
sub leaveInfo{
   ...
   return @arro;
}
```

despite the claim that you have

```
sub leaveInfo{
   ...
   print @arro;
}
```

That's actually a good thing.

---

`@array` in list context evaluates to a list of the values.

`@array` in scalar context evaluates to the number of elements in the array.

The concatenation operator necessarily evaluates its operands in scalar context, so that's why you're getting the number of elements in the array.

```
@a = qw( a b c d );
print @a."\n";   # 4
```

In your case, you could use

```
print '... confirm("... '
    . join(' ', leaveInfo(1215))
    . '");...';
```

Except that fails if any of the string contain `"` or `\`. Better:

```
sub to_js_str_literal {
   my ($s) = @_;
   $s =~ s/([\\"])/\\$1/g;
   return qq{"$s"};
}

print '... confirm("... "+'
    . to_js_str_literal(join(' ', leaveInfo(1215)))
    . ');...';
```